# How to change ISO-8859 text with CRLF line terminators

Tags: linux, character-encoding

I am trying to change the encoding of a text file to UTF-8.

I am new to Unix so any help would be great. I am not sure how to code it properly with recode function.

Comment: Are you aware there are two independent questions there? ISO-8859→UTF-8 and CR+LF→LF

Comment: @PabloA The question isn't asking about CRLF -> LF conversion though.

Comment: Which national variant of ISO-8859? Do you want to insert a BOM? If all you've got is a 7-bit ASCII file and you don't want a BOM there's no practical difference.

Comment: Also check that it really is ISO 8859-1 and not Windows code page 1252 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Answer (score 4):

Most immediate would probably be using **[iconv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv)**

The way suggested in the manual ( `iconv -f ISO88592 -t UTF8 < input.txt > output.txt` ) might not work with ISO-8859 as parameter since the subpart of the norm (-1… -9… -14…) is likely to be needed but… iconv should be able to automatically recognize the encoding of the source file. So… simply try :

```
iconv -t UTF-8 yourfilename
```

Additionally, and as wisely suggested by [Marcus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/106650/marcus-m%C3%BCller), if also willing to convert the dos-like line endings to *nix standards (CR-LF -> LF) you can use [`dos2unix`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix).
Note that depending on your distribution you might need to install some extra package. In case this causes problems, you can also use more standard tools for removing the CR :

Using tr : `tr -d '\r' < yourfilename_withCRLF > yourfilename_LFonly`

Using sed : `sed -i 's/\r$//g' youfilename_withCRLF`

Comment: … and to convert the line endings, `dos2unix`.